# Need to Remove Duplicates from a large Xml

Tags: xml, duplicates

I need to remove Duplicates from a large XML file(around 150 MB).
I have custom coded it,And,It is working for smaller XML's(around 50 KB)

How can i proceed this for Larger XML files.Code is added below:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->load('xml/in/100values.xml');

// print_r($doc);
$book = $doc->documentElement;


$nodes_usa = $book->getElementsByTagName('t__thl__usa');
$nodes_city = $book->getElementsByTagName('t__p__city');
$nodes_prov = $book->getElementsByTagName('t__p__province');
$temp_usa = [];
$temp_city = [];
$temp_prov = [];
for ($i = 0; $i < $nodes_usa->length; $i++) {
    $nodeusa = $nodes_usa->item($i);
    $nodecity = $nodes_city->item($i);
    $nodeprov = $nodes_prov->item($i);
    $searches = array_keys($temp_usa, $nodeusa->nodeValue);
    if(!empty($searches)){
        foreach($searches as $search_i){
            if($temp_city[$search_i] == $nodecity->nodeValue && $temp_prov[$search_i] == $nodeprov->nodeValue){
                $nodeusa->parentNode->parentNode->removeChild($nodeusa->parentNode);
                $i--;
            }else{
                $temp_usa[] = $nodeusa->nodeValue;
                $temp_city[] = $nodecity->nodeValue;
                $temp_prov[] = $nodeprov->nodeValue;
            }
        }
    }else{
        $temp_usa[] = $nodeusa->nodeValue;
        $temp_city[] = $nodecity->nodeValue;
        $temp_prov[] = $nodeprov->nodeValue;
    }
}
$doc->formatOutput = true; 
$test1 = $doc->saveXML(); // put string in test1


$doc->save('xml/out/duplicates_removed.xml'); // save as file
```

I have ideantified the duplicates based on tags :t__thl__usa,t__p__city,t__p__province

Comment: can you add a valid minimal XML sample including duplicates to your question?

Comment: Also, what's your programming language ?

Comment: I'm using PHP, sorry for not mentioning it earlier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the programming language you're using, but this looks very much like you're comparing every item with every other item, giving quadratic performance. That simply won't scale to a large file.

This kind of thing is always easier in XSLT

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="..." group-by="...">
  <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()[1]"/>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

This retains the first item in each group and drops the others.

Comment: I'm using PHP, sorry for not mentioning it earlier